# How to uninstall RHEL from a dual-boot system?

Tags: linux, grub, dual-boot, rhel

I had RHEL 5 and WinXP on dual-boot and then from WinXP I deleted those partitions which were allocated to RHEL. Now I am not able to start my computer. The booting process stops at grub. I tried installing XP again so that it repairs the MBR for XP but the bootable CD is not initiating the installation process. How can I recover my winXP?

Edit : I will not mind formatting the drive where XP is installed (in my case it's in C drive).

Problem solved : Thank you guys for your help and support. I tried the RHEL cd and then in the command mode I tried `fdisk -l` and it showed that 1 partition was being used by Linux. I deleted that and then booted through WinXP CD and followed the steps which zypher suggested and it worked.

Comment: I'm kinda confused, you are willing to reinstall XP, but are not ready to format the drive where it is installed? Were you able to reinstall XP?

Comment: Did I say I will mind? Check again.

Comment: Urgh sorry, I missed the "mind". Anyway it's good that you have your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you boot to your windows installation CD, you should see an option called "repair console" or something similar. Select that, it will bring up a dos prompt. Type the following commands:

`fixboot` then `fixmbr` and reboot, you should be good after that unless there is something wrong with your windows install.

Comment: I tried that but when I boot from windows CD. A message comes which says Setup is checking the hardware and then it stops responding.

Comment: @Chankey generally that means either a hardware issue, or there is something wrong w/ the install media.

Comment: Media is correct, no problem with that. Hardware was working good too, just before I deleted those partitions.

Comment: @chankey i ment that there is something physically wrong with the media. Can you boot to something like an ubuntu live cd?